# Android source code compilation takes too long

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on Kitkat Android source for imx6. The problem is whenever I add more debug prints to any of the .java files [for ex: WiFiMonitor.java] I see that the compilation takes more than an hour to complete. Adding a few prints for debugging and ending up waiting for an hour to complete, is too long for me. Can someone suggest how to finish off the compilation [considering that only a single file is changed] in very less time. Is there any specific command which will cause Android to compile only the changed file and thereby reduce the compilation time? The command that I use for compilation is:

## make -j3

Please someone help me out with this.

Comment: only debugging taking time ?

Comment: Compilation taking too much time

Comment: possibility is you might have to many library files or library projects .. In that case whole things will be compiled ..

Comment: Try reducing library projects only copy important java files

Comment: Do you have any library project ? and only few parts you are using ?